# On listbox double click open new form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Im using windowsForms c# have a listbox which is bound with data items ...So depending on double click of the listbox item i want the corressponding form open...thnx in adv

Comment: What have  you tried so far?

Comment: i dont knw how to proceed so needed some help

Comment: ok, but we need some context. When you say the "corressponding form", how do you identy it? Do you have an array of forms? Do these forms have an identifier?

Comment: No I havnt created an array of forms...i Have just created the forms...bt from the dataset i know which form has to be opened...the dataset name and Forms which i have created Have same Names

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox` has an `DoubleClick` event. You can access it if you select object, open `Events` tab in a `Properties` window.

Double click it and Visual Studio will create an event handler for you like this:

```
public void ListBox1_OnDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here is your code
}
```

Now, you just need to enter your code.
If you want to open a form with a corresponding item then it will be something like:

```
public void ListBox1_OnDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = listBox1.Text; // Don't forget to manipulate with it

    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to `DoubleClick` event on `ListBox`

```
listBox1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_DoubleClick);

private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // logic here
}
```

or

```
listBox1.DoubleClick += (s,e) => { /*logic here */};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the MouseDoubleClick Event, it provides the cursor position in `MouseEventArgs` so you can easily detect which item got doubleclicked.

```
void Listbox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{     
        int index = Listbox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
        {
          object clickedItem = Listbox1.Items[index];
          // open your form here
        }                
}
```